# flash as3 netStream video. How to skip 3 seconds forward/backward while playing video?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, time, skip

I have NetStream attached to video control in flash movie.
I cannot understand how to jump forward or backward.

```
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler); 
ns.play("Video.flv"); 
vid.attachNetStream(ns);
```

I need somethinf like

```
btnSkip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClicked);
function playClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
ns.pause();
//ns.step(1000)
//ns.seek(1);
ns.resume();
}
```

ns.step() - doesn't work and I don't know why.
ns.seek - works fine, but I don't know where is a position, there's no ns.position and no ns.fps properties to add ns.seek(ns.position+(ns.fps*3)) to skip 3 seconds forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather simple actually. Use the seek method on your netStream. To get the position use the time method and then add the offset you need

For 3 sec forward:

```
ns.seek(ns.time + 3);
```

For 3 sec backward:

```
ns.seek(ns.time - 3);
```

Comment: Thanx, guys.It was my misunderstanding of seek() method =))

Answer (score 1):

This article might help you a little further: [Netstream and step() or seek()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365479/netstream-and-step-or-seek).

What are you trying to play? If it's just a static video you might be able to use the regular video objects, then you'll be able to use the playheadTime property (which might not be very accurate by the way - depending on the number of keyframes).

Good luck!